# Adding a new field to table in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, attribute-table, arccatalog

I have a command button in ArcMap, this command button working to add a new field to a specific table in ArcCatalog.

e.g. i have a table contains many fields like ObjectID , FeatureName, ... 
i want to add a new field programmatically while ArcMap is running .

Is there anyway to add a new field to ArcCatalog while the ArcMap is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the solution :

```
ITable woTable ;
            ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)woTable;
            IField newField = this.WOAttributeProperties.getOrSetField;
            try
            {
                schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
                woTable.AddField(newField);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("An Error Occured: " + exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the lock to shared, whether or not an error occurred.
                schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "add a new field to ArcCatalog" but from ArcMap you could just locate (best to use Search window in ArcGIS 10 or ArcToolbox previously) the [Add Field tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000) and run it to add a new field.

Comment: i already have a table, contains many fields e.g. OBJECTID , FeatureName, ... i want to add a new field programmatically, i know that you can't add a new field to ArcCatalog While ArcMap running, i am asking if there is anyway to add a new field to ArcCatalog while ArcMap is running. hope it's clear now. Regards

Comment: I very rarely use ArcCatalog since the release of 10.0 - is there a reason why you have to do this in ArcCatalog rather than from ArcMap (or a standalone program) with ArcCatalog closed?

Comment: i had to do it in ArcCatalog. if i create a new desktop program, i guess it will be working fine, but i prefer to do it in a command button in the ArcMap. and thanks for your replying.

Comment: @SWAIS: Every toolbox and tool in ArcCatalog is also available in ArcMap.